# Can we specified format rules directly in file loaded in Excel?

Tags: excel, file, csv, format, loading

I'm generating a csv file that looks like:

```
column1,column2,column3
hello,02,some comments
hello,AF,some comments
hello,15,some comments
hello,08,some comments
hello,FF,some comments
```

When opening into Excel, the second columns will convert automatically 02 to 2 and 08 to 8.

Recommended workaround is to tweak settings in Excel or specifying format of each columns during the file loading. (time-consuming, not user-friendly)

Another workaround for file itself, would be to append quotes around the concerned values, so they would be treated as strings. 
(for some reasons, I can't do this, as the file I generate, must reflect the original source one)

But... Is there another way ?

Like adding some kind of a commentary line, containing hints for the Excel parser, directly in the CSV.

Taking Oracle SQL queries hints system as an example, which allows us to change the query optimizer way of work.

I'm not sure this exists for Excel, maybe it is, but obscure and not well documented ?

I can't figure out why they would not add such a useful feature to "preconfigure" the format instead of having the user to navigate Excel settings.

Thanks

Comment: when you use the **add data..** option in excel, you can choose the columns datatype where you should be able to use text.

Comment: If user-friendlyness is really important to you, generate a true Excel file with all needed formatting in place. Plenty of libraries available which can generate Excel files.